# Allow each user to have a single session

Tags: java, jsp

The webapp I'm working on is running JSP and JAVA in the backed on Tomcat server. 
How would it be possible to only allow each user to have only one session at a time, meaning not allowing any user to sign in more than one from same or other machine/browser.

The JSP client side:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"> <br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"> <br>


<input type="submit" value="Login">
<% String fail = request.getParameter("loginFailed");


    if(fail != null && fail.equals("yes"))
    {
        out.println("<br><font color=\"red\"> Login failed</font>");
    }
    else if(request.getParameter("loggedOut") != null)
    {
        out.println("<br><font color=\"red\">You have been logged out.</font>");
    }

    %>
```

JAVA Part:

```
public class login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public login() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] uname = request.getParameterValues("uname");
    String[] pass = request.getParameterValues("pwd");

    if( uname.length == 0 || pass.length == 0)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/MASC/index.jsp?loginFailed=yes");
        return;
    }

    UsersDB authdb = new UsersDB();
    User authUser = null;
    try {
        authUser = authdb.auth(uname[0], pass[0]);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(authUser == null)
    {
        response.getWriter().append("not authenitacted");
        Cookie authCookie = new Cookie("auth", "no");

        response.addCookie(authCookie);
        response.sendRedirect("/MASC/index.jsp?loginFailed=yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("auth session  " + authUser);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("uid", authUser.getUid());
        session.setAttribute("level", authUser.getLevel());
        session.setAttribute("aeid", authUser.getAeid());

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);

        response.sendRedirect("/MASC/welcome.jsp");
    }


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Is there a way to store the logged in users, or create a new column in the database "Loggedin" and check for that column before allowing user to sign in? Or is there any more efficient way to implement that ?

Comment: If you choose to use spring security, it has a feature called concurrency-control that controls the number of concurrent sessions a user is allowed to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd need to define what should happen when user logs in using a different session. Remember, if the user closed the browser, your server is *not* notified, so a new session can even be from a restart of the same browser.

Given that, I think the only way it makes sense, is to invalidate the existing session of the user, when the user logs in again.

To do that, you should create an application-scoped attribute (on `ServletContext`) with a map of user to active session. When logging in, you replace the current entry, if any. For every other access, if current session is not the active session, redirect to login page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map with userid as key and session object as value. Whenever a login request is received first check in this map the value corresponding to user id. If the value is not null, it means a session already exist for this user. So either invalidate the existing session and create a new one or use the previous one and display a message to user that user is already logged in. Point to note is that whenever a user log off, its entry in the map must be removed. You can use sessioncontextlistener for this.